# Why height and width of elements are not same as it is specified in CSS?

Tags: css

Why height and width of elements are not same as it is specified in CSS ?

Here is the link to jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/sunnycpp/2hNkk/

Same code is copy-pasted over here,

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>  
<div id="target">
  <p>Click here set promise as Done!</p>
</div> 
<br/>
<div id="reset" ><p>Reset</p></div>  
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
DIV {      
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center; 
  margin-bottom: 10px;     
}

#target {
  width:200;
  height:200;
  background-color:yellow;
}

#reset {
  width:100;
  height:100;
  background-color:grey;
  color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify **units** (px, em, %) for any measurements in CSS:

```
#target {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add 'px' ->

```
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
```